# Keeping track what the state parameters are

Tags: c#, design-patterns, flags, states

I'm refactoring software that is created by my predecessor. The software can communicate over the can-bus. At this moment all devices are hardcoded in the software and my job is to make every deviceType configurable. (Saved in serialized classes and creatable with a Model creator).
With the software, the devices can be configured, addressed and parameter set.

At the moment, it keeps track of the messages with flagged enums set in the uints paramsRequested and paramsUpdated. But this needs to be replaced with something else. Because this is not scaleable and configurable.

Example enum:

```
public enum FunctionParameters : uint
{
    None = 0,
    StatusInterval = 1 << 0,
    Delay = 1 << 1,
    Time = 1 << 2,
    .....
}
```

A mesage is sent over the can-bus and is waiting asynchronosly on a reply.

When message comes in:

```
_paramsUpdated |= (uint) FunctionParameters.StatusInterval;
```

Another thread waits till message is arrived, to use it and checks if parameter isreceived.

```
while (((uint)_paramsUpdated & (uint)param) == 0)
{
    // Do nothing
    Thread.Sleep(threadSleepTimeMS);
    //Thread.Yield();
}
```

When this takes too long, it will give a timeout exception. This works as intended at the moment.

The question is, are there alternatives that don't work with enum flags to keep track of this, because the new situation has multiple flexible flags.

I do not have time-out issues, it's more a architectual problem to replace enum flags with another system.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Why does it take too long time? Why don't you simply increase number of consumer\producer threads?

Comment: @Kilanny Added some comments to make question more clear.

Comment: What about semaphores?

Comment: Furthermore, do these have to be threads? Can't you use call backs? or the observer pattern?

Comment: While not exactely related, I asked [a question a while ago about a similar issue](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/278405/should-i-represent-physical-accessories-of-a-system-as-classes-in-software), with some enlightening answers. Now, looking at your legacy code, and considering it is C#, the API, so to say, is a bit _too_ low level. What you could try to do is wrap these low-level method calls inside some semantically meaningful classes, and use some sort of polymorphism. Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: @CommuSoft Will take a look at semaphores, it looks good for now. About threads, it is not possible to use callbacks because it communicates with a can-bus.

Comment: @heltonbiker The accepted answer of your link is exactly the thing i'm trying to do. But then the flags enum does not fit anymore in this design.

Comment: @CommuSoft I'm not sure if semaphores are the one i need. I don't want to limit concurrent threads, i only want to keep track if all requested parameters are updated.

Comment: @Gulpener: but now you seem to perform a lot of "useless" pollings.

Comment: @CommuSoft But would that fix the problem that i need to replace the FlagEnum, or will it only improve performance?

Comment: @Gulpener from what you said it's not clear what you need to be changed to go from "a list of hardcoded devices" to "a dynamic, expandable collection of self-describing devices". Currently we are planning to implement our new system by having each device to tell its own number_id, and the software uses a factory pattern with alook-up table to find out how to initialize the corresponding software object. That's what I meant with polymorphism: the function "get id" would be implemented by every device, only the value return would differ.

Comment: Also, when you have legacy code using an obsolete object model, and you need a newer, more flexible object model, you should implement the new model as you actually want it (and not carrying over the old, obsolete requirements or restrictions) and then create some _wrapper_ classes which present the newer interface (with higher level functions) while encapsulating all this lower-level, bit-manipulation functions.

Comment: @heltonbiker Thats what i'm designing. But i don't know how you think I should solve my problem. 
The problem is, the function parameter enum has all parameters that it can hold. The problem is that this is limited and i want to have indefinit possible parameters.

Comment: From what you have written, it's hard to tell, because it doesn't seem possible to understand how your system is working now from the few code blocks you posted. So, it is hard to know what can and what cannot change on the legacy code. Also, other commenters seem focused on the timeout part, while you seem more concerned on the architecture part, am I right? And if yes, don't you think you should have focused the question more on that part?

Comment: @heltonbiker Im indeed working on the achitecture part. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maybe have the solution myself:

I added a class named ParameterFlag; This looks linke this:

```
    public class ParameterFlag
    {
        public ParameterFlag(ParameterType parameterType, bool flag)
        {           
            ParameterType = parameterType;
            Flag = flag;
        }

        public ParameterType ParameterType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool Flag
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

_paramsUpdated will become:

```
    List<ParameterFlag> _paramsUpdated
```

When a message comes in:

```
    ParameterFlag flag =_paramsUpdated.Find(x=> x.ParameterType == ParameterType);
    flag.Flag = true;
```

Another thread waits till message is arrived, to use it and checks if parameter isreceived:

```
private void WaitParameterReceived(ParameterType param)
{
    while (!_paramsUpdated.Find(x => x.ParameterType == param).Flag)
    {
       // Do nothing
       Thread.Sleep(threadSleepTimeMS);
       //Thread.Yield();
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your comments!